# Derivative of a general form of a function in maple

Tags: maple

I have used maple to solve numerically the biharmonic equation. 
$$\Delta^{2} h(r)=0$$
and then i added an external potential so it became like this
$$\Delta^{2} h(r) + c\cdot h(r)=0$$ where c is a giving constant
now i want to generalize the form of h(r).
So i want to add  $$V(h(r))$$ which is a general function of the height field $$h(r)$$
so now i want to solve this 
$$\Delta^{2} h(r) + V^{'}(h(r))=0$$
where i added the derivative of V.

How can i write in maple? $$V^{'}(h(r))$$

Comment: By the way, instead of $*$, use **\cdot** to generate $\cdot$ or **\times** to generate $\times$.